# ColdFusion/Java APNS - intermittent results

Tags: java, ios, coldfusion, notifications

I am having strange/intermittent results when testing Push Notifications using the Java Apple Push Notification Service Library (http://notnoop.github.io/java-apns/) with ColdFusion.

Here is a sample of a Payload string that works:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"dsfkjsdlfkjasdlfkjsdlfkjasdlkfjasldfkjasldkfjasdlkfjasldkfjasldkfjasdlkfjasldkfjasdlkfjasdlfkjasdlkfjasdlkfjasldkfjasldkfjasldkfjasldkfjasldkfjasldkfjasldkfjalsdkfjlasdkfjaslkdjf"},"ID":"431"}
```

When I send a notification with additional custom fields and "short" message text, it goes through. Sample:

```
{"ALERTTYPE":"Collection","ID":"427","ALERTVALUE":"50","aps":{"alert":"005 - Source: Eric Dev PC;"}}
```

However, when I try to send a notification with "longer" text, the notification does not go through.

For example, I sent a notification with a Link to Collection with the message text “004 - Source: Eric Dev PC;”, and I received it, but, when I sent a notification with a Link to Collection and the message text “004 - Source: Eric Dev PC; Certificate: ABC123; Link to Collection: Collection 123;”, it did not go through. I inspected the Payload on the “longer” one before attempting to push it, and it is not large – 158 bytes (I believe the maximum is 2048 bytes). I am also using the `isTooLong()` method to check the Payload and shorten it with `shrinkBody()` to ensure that the Payload is not too large.

```
{"ALERTTYPE":"Collection","ID":"427","ALERTVALUE":"50","aps":{"alert":"005 - Source: Eric Dev PC; Certificate: ABC123; Link to Collection: Collection 123;"}}
```

Again, this Payload is well below the threshold.

Here is my code:

```
//  Create the ApnsService object
LOCAL.ApnsService =
    CreateObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.APNS")
        .newService()
        .withCert(
            VARIABLES.ApnsCertificate["filePath"],
            VARIABLES.ApnsCertificate["password"]
            )
        .withProductionDestination()
        .build();

//  Start the Apns service
LOCAL.ApnsService.start();

//  Set default value for Connection Test status
LOCAL.ConnectionTestSuccess = true;

/*
    Test the connection - this will throw an exception if the Apple
    servers aren't reachable or the service cannot send
    notifications for now (attempt will be made at next scheduled
    time)
*/
try {
    LOCAL.ApnsService.testConnection();
}
catch (any error){
    LOCAL.ConnectionTestSuccess = false;
}

//  Connection Test worked, so attempt to send the Notification
if  (LOCAL.ConnectionTestSuccess) {
    /*
        Before attempting to send the push notification, retrieve
        and deactivate inactive device tokens to prevent issues
        with Apple
    */
    deleteInactiveDevices(apnsCert=VARIABLES.ApnsCertificate);

    //  Retrieve all User Device Tokens for this Push Notification
    LOCAL.qUserDeviceTokens = getUserDeviceTokens();

    LOCAL.aDeviceTokens =
        ListToArray(ValueList(LOCAL.qUserDeviceTokens.DEVICETOKEN));

    //  Generate a Payload Builder instance
    LOCAL.PayloadBuilder =
        CreateObject("java", "com.notnoop.apns.APNS")
            .newPayload();

    //  Add the alert body to the payload
    LOCAL.PayloadBuilder
        .alertBody(Trim(VARIABLES.MessageText));

    //  Build the Custom Fields object/structure
    LOCAL.CustomFields.id = VARIABLES.Id;

    //  Link to News Article
    if  (Len(Trim(VARIABLES.NewsArticleId))) {
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertType = "News";
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertValue = Trim(VARIABLES.NewsArticleId);
    }
    //  Link to Collection
    else if  (Len(Trim(VARIABLES.CollectionId))) {
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertType = "Collection";
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertValue = Trim(VARIABLES.CollectionId);
    }
    //  Link to Search Results
    else if (Len(Trim(VARIABLES.SearchText))) {
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertType = "Search";
        LOCAL.CustomFields.alertValue = Trim(VARIABLES.SearchText);
    }

    //  Add Custom Fields to the Payload
    LOCAL.PayloadBuilder
        .customFields(LOCAL.CustomFields);

    /*
        Shrink the alert body so that the entire payload
        string will fit within Apple's byte limit
    */
    if  (LOCAL.PayloadBuilder.isTooLong()) {
        LOCAL.PayloadBuilder
            .shrinkBody("...");
    }

    LOCAL.PayloadJSONString =
        LOCAL.PayloadBuilder
            .build();

    /*
        Push the notification through Apple's APNS;
            Note: push() accepts a Java Collection and a Java
            String. ColdFusion Arrays are already typed as Java
            Collections, so there is no need to recast it
    */
    LOCAL.Notifications =
        LOCAL.ApnsService
            .push(
                LOCAL.aDeviceTokens,
                JavaCast("string", LOCAL.PayloadJSONString)
            );

//  Stop the Apns service
LOCAL.ApnsService.stop();
```

Quick update…. I sent a bunch of notifications with additional custom fields and reduced the number of characters in the message text one at a time. They appears to go through if the message text contains 32 characters or less (Payload byte length = 107) – anything more, and the notification is not received. Seems arbitrary…. Puzzling….

Comment: still having issue ?